# Custom filter 'filter' in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have a json array which contains months number and years. I am iterating that array in template and displaying month and year. I am using custom filter 'monthName' to convert month number to month names. Now I want to filter out the displayed list of month names and year based on user input. Cannot use angular js inbuilt filter on array as it contains month number and not names.

Here are the code snippets

JS

```
$scope.monthYr = [{month:"1", year: "2014"},{month:"2", year: "2015"},{month:"3", year: "2016"}

//custom filter to convert month number to month names
    app.filter('monthName', [function() {
        return function (monthNumber) { 
            var monthNames = [ 'January', 'February', 'March','April', 'May', 'June','July', 'August', 'September','October','November', 'December' ];
        return monthNames[monthNumber - 1];
    }
```

HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="item in monthYr ">
{{item.month | monthName}} &nbsp;({{item.year}})
</div>
```

So the list displayed is as follows -

```
January (2014)
February (2015)
March (2016)
```

So possible cases to match 'March (2016)' are when user inputs 'March' or '2016' or 'March (2016)'. So is it possible in Angularjs to built custom filter filter or call a function on filter for the expected result?

Answer (score 0):

In the same controller that you have defined `$scope.monthYr`, inject angularJs `$filter`, and do as the following

```js
$scope.filterMounthYr = function() {
  // $scope.search is the input value
  $scope.monthYr = $filter('filter')($scope.monthYr, $scope.search);
}
```

If you have problem understanding the code, comment, and I will answer.

Check this [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XqxvxB)

## Update

As you have commented the months in the list are numbers, but the input value is String. So I think you should go for the js built-in `filter` method.

```js
$scope.filteredMonthYr = $scope.monthYr
$scope.filterMonthYr = function() {
  var monthNames = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June',
    'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'
  ];

  // Trim the serached word
  var search = $scope.search.trim()

  // Check if the month list contains
  if (monthNames.includes(search)) {
    $scope.searchKey = String(monthNames.indexOf(search) + 1);
  } else {
    $scope.searchKey = search;
  }
  // Only return if one of the contditions stated is true
  $scope.filteredMonthYr = $scope.monthYr.filter(function(o) {
    return (o["month"] == $scope.searchKey) ||
      (o["year"] == $scope.searchKey) || ($scope.searchKey in o)
  })
}
```

---

The full code.

```js
angular
  .module('MonthYearApp', [])
  .controller("MonthYearController", function MonthYearController($scope) {

    $scope.monthYr = [{
      month: "1",
      year: "2014"
    }, {
      month: "2",
      year: "2015"
    }, {
      month: "3",
      year: "2016"
    }, {
      month: "4",
      year: "2016"
    }, {
      month: "5",
      year: "2016"
    }, {
      month: "6",
      year: "2016"
    }]

    $scope.filteredMonthYr = $scope.monthYr
    $scope.filterMonthYr = function() {
      var monthNames = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June',
        'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'
      ];

      // Trim the serached word
      var search = $scope.search.trim()

      // Check if the month list contains
      if (monthNames.includes(search)) {
        $scope.searchKey = String(monthNames.indexOf(search) + 1);
      } else {
        $scope.searchKey = search;
      }
      // Only return if one of the conditions is true
      $scope.filteredMonthYr = $scope.monthYr.filter(function(o) {
        return (o["month"] == $scope.searchKey) ||
          (o["year"] == $scope.searchKey) || ($scope.searchKey in o)
      })
    }
  }).filter('monthName', [function() {
    return function(monthNumber) {
      var monthNames = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June',
        'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'
      ];
      return monthNames[monthNumber - 1];
    }
  }])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.10/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="MonthYearApp">
  <div ng-controller="MonthYearController">
    <input type='text' data-ng-model='search'>
    <button ng-click='filterMonthYr()'>Filter</button>
    <table>
      <tr data-ng-repeat="item in filteredMonthYr">
        <td> {{item.month | monthName}} </td>
        <td>{{item.year}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

*This code does not work if you type if both month and year. You should implement that feature yourself. It is pretty straightforward.*

---

## Update

Use `ng-change` and an `if-else` statement inside the `filterMonthYr` function.

```js
angular
  .module('MonthYearApp', [])
  .controller("MonthYearController", function MonthYearController($scope) {

    $scope.monthYr = [{
      month: "1",
      year: "2014"
    }, {
      month: "2",
      year: "2015"
    }, {
      month: "3",
      year: "2016"
    }, {
      month: "4",
      year: "2016"
    }, {
      month: "5",
      year: "2016"
    }, {
      month: "6",
      year: "2016"
    }]

    $scope.filteredMonthYr = $scope.monthYr
    $scope.filterMonthYr = function() {
      var monthNames = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June',
        'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'
      ];

      // Trim the serached word
      var search = $scope.search.trim()

      // Check if the month list contains
      if (monthNames.includes(search)) {
        $scope.searchKey = String(monthNames.indexOf(search) + 1);
      } else {
        $scope.searchKey = search;
      }
      // Only return if one of the conditions is true
      var monthYr = $scope.monthYr.filter(function(o) {
        return (o["month"] == $scope.searchKey) ||
          (o["year"] == $scope.searchKey) || ($scope.searchKey in o)
      })

      if (monthYr.length > 0) {
        $scope.filteredMonthYr = monthYr
      } else {
        $scope.filteredMonthYr = $scope.monthYr
      }
    }
  }).filter('monthName', [function() {
    return function(monthNumber) {
      var monthNames = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June',
        'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'
      ];
      return monthNames[monthNumber - 1];
    }
  }])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.10/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="MonthYearApp">
  <div ng-controller="MonthYearController">
    <input type='text' data-ng-model='search' ng-change="filterMonthYr()">
    <button ng-click=''>Filter</button>
    <table>
      <tr data-ng-repeat="item in filteredMonthYr">
        <td> {{item.month | monthName}} </td>
        <td>{{item.year}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The array $scope.monthYr does contains month numbers and not names as stated already. So, how can $filter will filter out that array based on inputs from the user which will be month name or year or both?

Comment: Thanks @mahan. But any way of filtering the items on user input keystrokes, like we use angular filter filter html in this case?

Answer (score -1):

you should use a Regular expression to test each element in the array if match your condition and here is the expression `/(\[)?March(2016)?.*(\])?.[0-9]{4}/`
to check copy and paste this code in web console to view result:`/(\[)?March(2016)?.*(\])?.[0-9]{4}/.test('(March 2016)')` and change `test()` parameter.
and depending on test() returned boolean value will filter the array